# ARM, gdb debugging showing Flags

Tags: debugging, gdb, arm

How can I display the status registers or Flags that are set by the cmp statment in the gdb debugger for ARM? 
Can't seem to find a way to do so.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay not the best question the cpsr registers are shown with info register, would have seen that earlier if I had opened my eyes ;)